# Combine 3 Unlike Objects Into A Table

Tags: powershell

I have 3 objects that I have created. Each only has VM names in them. I am trying to combine the 3 objects into 3 columns. There is nothing to join them on. This is purely for aesthetics.

I have tried Hash Tables, but that just makes a staggered table.

Something similar to this.

```
| HBR VM     | RPO Violated| RPO Violations |
|:-----------|------------:|:--------------:|
| VM 1       | VM 6        | VM 2
| VM 2       |             | VM 6    
| VM 3       |             |     
| VM 4       |             |     
| VM 5       |             |     
| VM 6       |             |
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest way: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Combine-Objects-02516b79

```
$arguments = [Pscustomobject]@()

foreach ( $Property in $Object1.psobject.Properties){
    $arguments += @{$Property.Name = $Property.value}
}

foreach ( $Property in $Object2.psobject.Properties){
    $arguments += @{ $Property.Name= $Property.value} 
}

$Object3 = [Pscustomobject]$arguments
```

Comment: That does combine it, but into 1 column. I am trying to put results of 1 object in say column A, the next results in column B and then the next in column C.

Comment: `$i=0; cat List.csv | % {$_ + ',' + $(cat List2.csv)[$i]; $i++}` ?

Comment: That doesn't completely solve it, but maybe it helps you think of a new way to approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083425/powershell-how-to-merge-unique-headers-from-one-csv-to-another What about this?