# Combine two CSV files in powershell without changing the order of columns

Tags: powershell

I  have "a.csv" and "b.csv" . I tried to merge them with below commands

```
cd c:/users/mine/test 
Get-Content   a.csv, b.csv |  Select-Object -Unique | Set-Content -Encoding ASCII joined.csv
```

But I got Output file like b.csv added by end of the row of  a.csv. I wanted add  by end of the column of a.csv then b.csv columns should begin

```
Vm     Resource    SID
mnvb    vclkn     vxjcb
vjc.v   vnxc,m    bvkxncb

Vm      123     456     789
mnvb   apple    banana  orange 
vjc.v  lemon    onion   tomato
```

My expected output should be like below. Without changing the order

```
Vm     Resource    SID    123       456     789
mnvb    vclkn   vxjcb     apple    banana  orange 
vjc.v   vnxc,m  bvkxncb   lemon    onion   tomato
```

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join/) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Import-Csv a.csv | Join-Object (Import-Csv b.csv) -On Vm | Export-Csv joined.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083425/powershell-how-to-merge-unique-headers-from-one-csv-to-another), there are two ways to do it -

[Join-Object](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Join-Object.ps1) custom function by RamblingCookieMonster. This is short and sweet. After you import the function in your current PoSh environment, you can use the below command to get your desired result -

```
Join-Object -Left $a -Right $b -LeftJoinProperty vm -RightJoinProperty vm | Export-Csv Joined.csv -NTI
```

The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083425/powershell-how-to-merge-unique-headers-from-one-csv-to-another/45085058#45085058) from [mklement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0?tab=profile) which would work for you as below -

```
# Read the 2 CSV files into collections of custom objects.
# Note: This reads the entire files into memory.
$doc1 = Import-Csv a.csv
$doc2 = Import-Csv b.csv

$outFile = 'Joined.csv'

# Determine the column (property) names that are unique to document 2.
$doc2OnlyColNames = (
  Compare-Object $doc1[0].psobject.properties.name $doc2[0].psobject.properties.name |
    Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>'
).InputObject

# Initialize an ordered hashtable that will be used to temporarily store
# each document 2 row's unique values as key-value pairs, so that they
# can be appended as properties to each document-1 row.
$htUniqueRowD2Props = [ordered] @{}

# Process the corresponding rows one by one, construct a merged output object
# for each, and export the merged objects to a new CSV file.
$i = 0
$(foreach($rowD1 in $doc1) {
  # Get the corresponding row from document 2.
  $rowD2 = $doc2[$i++]
  # Extract the values from the unique document-2 columns and store them in the ordered
  # hashtable.
  foreach($pname in $doc2OnlyColNames) { $htUniqueRowD2Props.$pname = $rowD2.$pname }
  # Add the properties represented by the hashtable entries to the
  # document-1 row at hand and output the augmented object (-PassThru).
  $rowD1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $htUniqueRowD2Props -PassThru
}) | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Utf8 $outFile
```

Comment: ..If I dont want to remove duplicate columns.What needs to be change from the above code

Comment: I doubt you could achieve that with the above code cause if you try to use`Add-Member` to add the `VM` column for **b.csv**, it would complain that the member `VM` already exists.
You could use something like - `gc $a = a.csv; gc $b = b.csv; 0..($b.Count – 1) | %{$a[$_],$b[$_] -join ','} | Out-File $outFile`